# React Navigation problems

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Help me please. I am making mobile app. I have bottom tab navigation that is making navigation between 3 main pages. I have done navigation between 1st page and second,but not with tab bottom navigation, with button. When i have made this i have not got something i want. I will be very happy if you help me. When i navigate to second page from first i have 2 titles. But i want to make 1:
[image]

there is 2 titles, first is < and second is "Courses", i want to make it like this "< Courses". Help me please. Code:

```html
// 1st page

import Courses from './Courses'

<Button
onPress={() => {
   navigate('Courses')
}}
 title="More courses"
/>

  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      Courses: {
        screen: Courses,
      },
      Details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }
```

App.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Home from './screens/Home'
import Courses from './screens/Courses'
import Editor from './screens/Editor'
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';



const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Home',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },

  Courses:{
    screen:Courses,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Courses',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-school" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Editor:{
    screen:Editor,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Editor',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-document" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },

},{
  tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor:'#db0202',
    inactiveTintColor:'grey',
    style:{
      fontSize:3,
      height:45,
      backgroundColor:'white',
      borderTopWidth:0,
      elevation: 5
    }
  }
});



export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the bottom tab bar?

Comment: And the code for `Courses`, if possible.

Comment: @zaytrix code for bottom tab bar:

Comment: Is the first code block your code for screens/Home? And is that all of it because it looks like it's missing the code for HomeScreen and DetailsScreen.

Comment: @zaytrix first code in for Home. In this code i gave you the most important code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define another navigator in your Home screen. If you define Home like this it should work:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Button, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation: { navigate } } = this.props
    <Button
      title='More Courses'
      onPress={() => navigate('Courses')}
    />
  }
}
```

Your other screens should look similar to this.